# Laravel - Some Options of Input Not Displaying

Tags: php, input, laravel-4

. Hello y'all! I'm trying to have a select input with multiple options on a form. I have several of these but for some reason one is not displaying all of its options. I have tried removing the #'s, changing the order to try to figure out which one specifically is causing the error, and writing the options in a different format, all with no success. If you have any idea why this might be or if I am just unaware of some related syntax restriction please let me know! Thank you so much!

HTML:

```
{{ Form::select('shelf',
    array(
        '' => 'Shelf',
        '6' => 'SPF 1 x 6 x 6',
        '8' => 'SPF 1 x 2 x 8',
        '8' => 'SPF 1 x 4 x 8',
        '1' => 'WRC 1 x 4 x 8 #1',
        '2' => 'WRC 1 x 4 x 8 #2',
        '1' => 'WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #1',
        '2' => 'WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #2',
        '8' => 'WRC 1 x 2 x 8', 
        '8' => 'WRC 2 x 2 x 8',     
    ), null,
    array('class' => 'shelf', 'id' => null)) 
}}
```

So far "Shelf" is displayed in the select as the standard option but when clicked the only other options are SPF 1x6x6 , WRC 2x2x8 , WRC 1x6x8 #1 , and WRC 1x6x8 #2 in that order. Any and all help and pointers would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
array(
   ''  => 'Shelf', // --> unique
   '6' => 'SPF 1 x 6 x 6', // --> unique
   '8' => 'SPF 1 x 2 x 8', // --> Not unique/8
   '8' => 'SPF 1 x 4 x 8', // --> Not unique/8
   '1' => 'WRC 1 x 4 x 8 #1', // --> Not unique/1
   '2' => 'WRC 1 x 4 x 8 #2', // --> Not unique/2
   '1' => 'WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #1', // Not unique/1 (This will replace all previous 1)
   '2' => 'WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #2', // --> Not unique/1 (This will replace all previous 2)
   '8' => 'WRC 1 x 2 x 8', --> Not unique/8,
   '8' => 'WRC 2 x 2 x 8', --> Not unique/8, (This will replace all previous 8)
 )
```

It's because your `array` contain duplicate keys and the first key is being replaced by the last duplicate key, means that, if you have two `'2'` then the second `'2'` will replace the first `'2'`, use unique `array keys/option value`. Otherwise you will get this:

```
<select class="shelf" name="shelf">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Shelf</option>
    <option value="6">SPF 1 x 6 x 6</option>
    <option value="8">WRC 2 x 2 x 8</option>
    <option value="1">WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #1</option>
    <option value="2">WRC 1 x 6 x 8 #2</option>
</select>
```